# Output file PDF with Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, pdf

i need your help or advice from output file pdf with jquery . i have problem from output file because pdf file don't out . this script jquery and html:

```
<script>
$("#msg").hide();
$("button").click(function() {
    var subject = $("#subject").val();
    var client = $("#client").val();

    $.ajax ({
        url: "http://localhost/report/fpdf_report.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: { subject: subject, client: client },
        success: function(data) {
            $("#msg").html(data);
            $("#msg").fadeIn("slow").delay(2000);
        },
        error: function(xhr) {
            alert(xhr+"error");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

`<input type="text" id="subject" /> <input type="text" id="client" />
<input type="text" id="client" />
<button>PDF</button>
<br />
<div id="msg"></div>`

so for script php convert pdf :

```
<?php
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$client = $_POST['client']; 
require ('fpdf/fpdf.php');
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf -> AddPage();
$pdf -> SetFont('Arial','B',20);
$pdf -> Cell(40,10,$subject);
$pdf -> Cell(50,20,$client);
$pdf -> Output();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of your php script is a PDF file, so you can't use a div.

You'll need an [object](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_object.asp) element like:

```
<object id="msg" type="application/pdf" data="test1.pdf">
Unable to open the PDF file.
</object>
```

and you'll need to save the PDF result on a file doing something like this:

```
$filename = '/path/of/my/file/test.pdf';
$pdf -> Output($filename, 'F');
echo $filename;
```

so with JQuery you need to change de data attribute of the object element, with the result of the Ajax POST (the result will be the name of the PDF File).

```
$.ajax ({
        url: "http://localhost/report/fpdf_report.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: { subject: subject, client: client },
        success: function(data) {
            $("#msg").attr("data", data);
        },
        error: function(xhr) {
            alert(xhr+"error");
        }
    });
```